# How to make krunner and other launchers show links, not only files

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, search, krunner, application-finder

When I enter the name of a file located in `~/` in one of the default folders it is immediately found. But links to other files and folders are not.

In order to easily access some files and folders with the launchers I have created links for them in locations like `~/Documents` or `~/Videos`. Those files are in folders with many levels on a separate drive and are not shown with a normal search/indexing by Krunner, Application Dashboard or Application Launcher, and in Xfce, for example, their links in $HOME made them searchable.

(So, I have created application launchers, desktop files for such files and folders located on a separate drive and that I open often, but not often enough as to see them all the time under "recent files" category search. Creating "launchers" for files and folders is cumbersome though.)

Is this expected behavior? Can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

> Those files are in folders with many levels on a separate drive and
> are not shown with a normal search/indexing by Krunner, Application
> Dashboard or Application Launcher

That is a bug or a bad setting. The separate drives *should* be scanned and shown in search once the drive was added in "File search" settings. (And that was a bug or problem that now is largely gone for me.)

Anyway, in case that still happens, and some folders that are often accessed are still not found by search in Krunner or Application launchers, possible solutions could be:

- add separately the folders to the list of "File search" settings
- considering links links cannot be shown in file search as such, create a new folder in `$HOME` called 'Links', add different links to folders there and then just search for "links" to find *that* folder.
- those locations can be added to "Places" left panel in Dolphin